# MATLAB: Reading both Bytes of a Unsigned 16-bit binary file

Tags: matlab, integer, byte, binaryfiles

I have a binary Band Sequential (1-band, BSQ file), which is an unsigned 16-bit (2-byte) integer.

Currently I'm reading the whole (image) through [multibandread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/multibandread.html):

```
img=multibandread('IMAGE.bsq',[400 400 1],'uint16',0,'bsq','n');
```

What process in MATLAB would allow me to read both bytes individually? i.e. I would like to read the file into 2 new arrays in MATLAB e.g. byte1 (400x400x1) and byte2 (400x400x1).

Can this be achieved through [fread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fread.html)? I note in the 'precision' section it is possible to skip source values (e.g. `'N*source=>output'`), but I'm unsure of the exact process.

Comment: Did you try specifying `'uint8'` instead of `'uint16'`, obtaining the result and then dividing it into two images? Or alternatively splitting your current result into two images using bitwise operations?

Comment: I need to extract both bytes from the `uint16` array - would reading as `uint8` achieve this? (I'm more interested in the data contained in the second byte though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be splitting your current `img` with bitwise operations. The LSB image would be:

```
img1 = bitand(img, 255);   %// 0x00FF
```

and the MSB image would be:

```
img2 = bitsra(img, 8);
```

Not mandatory, but maybe you'll also want to convert these into `uint8`s:

```
img1 = uint8(img1);
img2 = uint8(img2);
```

Comment: `img2 = bitsra(img, 8);` would be better.

Comment: That seems to have done it. I'm only really interested in the MSB which looks like it comes with reasonable values using `img1 = bitand(A, 255);   %// 0x00FF`. Cheers

Comment: @MBL I think the `img1` is LSB, not MSB. The `img2` is MSB.

Comment: @Masi That is what I stated in the answer, no?

Comment: @EitanT Yes, your answer is correct. MBL comments different in the second comment: *MSB --- img1*.

Comment: @EitanT: For people without the Fixed-Point Designer toolbox you might want to include your first answer with `bitand` as well.